# How do I add class or id in this element just knowing that there is more than one element containing " .sided-sections .widget "

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var b = ('data-type');

if ($(b + ":contains('cover')")) {
  $(".sided-sections .widget").addClass("cate-cover")
}
```

i want repair this code please because when I add this code it adds a class to all elements that contain " .sided-sections .widget " so I want to dedicate something to that where the class adds on data-type='cover' only and thank you

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery selector doesn't return a `true/false` value that can be used in `.match()`. If you want to know if a selector finds anything, you need to get its length.

Furthermore, `if` doesn't set `this` to the elements that the selector matches. If you want to set `this`, you need to use `.each()` to loop over all the matching elements.

```
$(b + ":contains('cover')").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".sided-sections .widget").addClass("cate-cover");
});
```

But you don't even need that, because you can apply `.siblings()` directly to the selector:

```
$(b + ":contains('cover')").siblings(".sided-sections .widget").addClass("cate-cover");
```

If this doesn't work, add the HTML to your question, and point out which elements should get the `cate-cover` class. You might have the relationships between the selectors wrong.

Comment: sorry my mr i don't understand , i want repair this code to add class in this element only but if i add a down code work in any class name “ .sided-sections .widget ” , i want help and thank you ,, sorry my english is bad


var b = ('data-type');

if ($(b + ":contains('cover')")) {
  $(".sided-sections .widget").addClass("cate-cover")
}

Comment: `if ($(b + ":contains('cover')"))` makes no sense. A selector returns a collection, and all collections are truthy. If you want to know if it matches something, you write `if ($(b + ":contains('cover')").length > 0)`

Comment: Please edit the question and add your HTML, showing what you expect the code to do.

Comment: i'm edit my question but i can't add code HTML But this is
      <b:section id='section1'>
        <b:widget id='HTML4' locked='false' title='post-sided' type='HTML' visible='true'>
          <b:widget-settings>
            <b:widget-setting name='content'><![CDATA[<i class="vnSection" data-type="sided" data-len="7" data-label="recent"></i>]]></b:widget-setting>
          </b:widget-settings>
          <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:include name='widget-title'/>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>

Comment: Why can't you add HTML code to the question? Mark it as code just like the JavaScript.

Comment: That doesn't look like normal HTML, I guess you're using a framework of some kind?